# BroadcastReceiver onReceive() thread safe?

Tags: android

Is `onReceive()` method of `BroadcastReceiver` thread safe or I need to implement synchronization on my own?

If I have any class level variable which is being used inside the `onReceive()` method, and the `onReceive()` method is called multiple times very quickly, would it cause an issue?

```
public class MyBroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    boolean isFirstTrigger = true;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
      if(isFirstTrigger)
       {
        //Do something time consuming
        isFirstTrigger = false;
       }
      }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is onReceive() method of BroadcastReceiver thread safe or I need to implement synchronization on my own?

It will only ever be called on the main application thread. Hence, it is thread-safe with respect to anything else running on the main application thread.

> If I have any class level variable which is being used inside the onReceive() method, and the onReceive() method is called multiple times very quickly, would it cause an issue?

If the `BroadcastReceiver` is registered in the manifest, a new instance is created for each broadcast. This is why you do not normally see data members on a `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: The BroadcastReceiver is registered in manifest and I have to work around the problem in which a network change broadcast is fired twice or thrice on some devices. I was thinking of using a class level variable. Now I am thinking of using SharedPreferences and storing the "isFirstTrigger" there, then setting it false after the processing is complete. But not sure if that will work or not (in case new instances are created and called up before the first call gets complete). Any Suggestions?

Comment: @Manish: Your process *probably* will stay around for a few seconds after a broadcast, and so you may be able to get away with a static data member. Otherwise, you will need to persist it, whether in `SharedPreferences` or elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare, my concern using SharedPreferences is: If multiple instances of BroadcastReceivers are created, wouldn't they all access the SharedPreference at the same time? It might happen that second and third invocation of onRecieve() occur before the first invocation updates the SharedPreference.

Comment: @Manish: "wouldn't they all access the SharedPreference at the same time?" -- as I wrote, `onReceive()` is called on the main application thread. There is **one** main application thread per process. Hence, by default, you are guaranteed that the three broadcasts will run serially.

Comment: the broadcastreceiver is registered in manifest(For network connected/disconnected event), even then it will be called serially?

Comment: @Manish: Yes. Let's try bold-italics this time: ***`onReceive()` is called on the main application thread***. It does not matter where you register the receiver, ***`onReceive()` is called on the main application thread***. It does not matter how many times the broadcast is sent, ***`onReceive()` is called on the main application thread***. It does not matter what your `Intent` filter looks like, ***`onReceive()` is called on the main application thread***. And since there is only one main application thread, by definition, `onReceive()` must be executed serially.

Comment: Beautifully explained. Thanks @CommonsWare! What got me confused was the broadcastreceiver was registered through manifest, not through any of my service/activity. But I understand it runs as part of the application process and that will have only one main thread.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I have question, presumably there are 2 pieces of data that published from 2 different background threads in the service into this `onReceive()`. Is it ok? Or I still need handler mechanism in this method for the data published from those 2 background threads in the service.

Comment: @Hey-men-whatsup: "Is it ok?" -- I cannot really answer that. `onReceive()` is called on the main application thread. The threads used by the senders of the broadcast do not matter. After all, for system broadcasts, the senders are in a completely separate app. Whether this behavior is OK or not is for you to decide, as I do not know what makes it OK or not.

Comment: Thanks I will take it as safe-operation (ok operation), since I've been running/simulating this case (outputting the data to the UI in this method) for almost 40 minutes now , and just fine. Thank you for all of your great answers