# Broadcast Receiver being called con-currently

Tags: android

I have a Broadcast Receiver that listens to app installation events.

What happens if multiple apps are being installed at the same time?

1. Will I get multiple calls or
2. Android might 'swallow' some of the calls and call me only once ?

Answer (score 0):

Each installation should send one braodcast intent. The answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18662618/broadcastreceiver-onreceive-thread-safe) can help you. As said in there:

> "If the BroadcastReceiver is registered in the manifest, a new
>   instance is created for each broadcast(...)"